# Global action filter in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Is it possible to create a global action filter that will automatically apply to all actions in all controllers in ASP.NET MVC application? I want something like "before_filter" defined in ApplicationController in Ruby on Rails.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can try to use [FluentFilter](http://fluentfilters.codeplex.com/) library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This really depends what you want to do with it.  In many scenarios, the previous answers by vucetica and Adeel will be what you actually want to do.  However, neither of them meet the criteria you listed:  **automatically** apply to **all actions/controllers**.

To do something like that, you would need to implement a handler for the Application BeginRequest event in Global.asax.  See the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.beginrequest.aspx) for more information.

*Update - July 27, 2010*: [ScottGu blogged about](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/27/introducing-asp-net-mvc-3-preview-1.aspx) MVC 3 Preview 1, which includes a framework for global filters like you're talking about.  They're registered via Global.asax, and can apply to all controllers or based on specific criteria.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. First I thought it would work but after trying this approach I noticed that Application_BeginRequest gets ALL the requests, including requests for .js, .css, .jpg and other resources for the page. So it would be run many times for one page and may be a serious overload. Is there an easy way to filter only the request for the page content and skip all the .js, .css, .jpg requests without parsing the requested URL?

Comment: You might be able to look at the information coming out of the routing engine to determine if you're dealing with a controller/action.  Honestly, Adeel's answer is the *right* way to do something like this, I was just pointing out that this is the alternative if you wanted an automatic, global handler.

Comment: If you don't want to wait for MVC3, my coworker wrote something that we use to automatically match filters with actions (either always, or based on a condition). This is dependent on Windsor for IOC but you can always modify that part. http://geekswithblogs.net/wesm/archive/2009/12/11/ijoined-filter.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Create your own base controller and inherit from it.

Comment: Thank you, it should work, but I'm looking for a really simple approach that will not require much coding.

Comment: @vucetice You should favor composition over inheritance