# Putting a common logic in every action of controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing a mvc app where i have lot of common functionality in every controller action.
My question is that where should i put  a common initilization logic in every action of controller

Comment: Use a Global Action Filter. This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334324/global-action-filter-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 2):

You have two choice.

- Action Filter
- create basecontroller and inherit all controller from basecontroller

see [this](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2010/06/28/action-filter-versus-controller-base-class.aspx) link for your reference

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to create an action filter ([see here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs)) and place the attribute in each action, you can create a controller that inherits from the base mvc controller and override the [OnActionExecuting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onactionexecuted.aspx) or [OnActionExecuted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onactionexecuting.aspx) method to provide common behavior for all actions in a controller.
Hope it helps