# common logic in multiple actions in Web API controllers

Tags: asp.net-web-api

**There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19336422/putting-a-common-logic-in-every-action-of-controller) already asked by someone BUT it was related to ASP.NET MVC and not Web API**. I have some common code which I want to execute in every action in Web API certain controllers. What is a good way for such situation?

Comment: Same answer, BaseController or ActionFilter...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Putting a common logic in every action of controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19336422/putting-a-common-logic-in-every-action-of-controller)

Comment: You can create and use attributes.

Comment: @GGO I have solved it using ActionFilter. You can post your reply as an official answer if you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.Net Web API and ASP.Net Wep MVC has the same core. Also you can use the same answer describe in your link :

- creating a BaseController and inherit all your controllers
- creating an ActionFilter like [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-custom-action-filters)