# How to configure HTML Minification in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, minify

I would like to configure HTML minification to my ASP>NET MVC5 web application.

I installed Nuget

```
Install-Package WebMarkupMin.Mvc
```

Then I add Filter Attributte:

```
[MinifyHtmlAttribute]
public ActionResult Index()
{           
    return View();
}
```

But the HTML minification does not work.

Nuget Installation add few lines to the web.config:

```
<sectionGroup name="webMarkupMin">
      <section name="core" type="WebMarkupMin.Core.Configuration.CoreConfiguration, WebMarkupMin.Core" />
      <section name="webExtensions" type="WebMarkupMin.Web.Configuration.WebExtensionsConfiguration, WebMarkupMin.Web" />
</sectionGroup>

<webMarkupMin xmlns="http://tempuri.org/WebMarkupMin.Configuration.xsd">
  <core>
    <css>
      <minifiers>
        <add name="NullCssMinifier" displayName="Null CSS Minifier" type="WebMarkupMin.Core.Minifiers.NullCssMinifier, WebMarkupMin.Core" />
        <add name="KristensenCssMinifier" displayName="Mads Kristensen's CSS minifier" type="WebMarkupMin.Core.Minifiers.KristensenCssMinifier, WebMarkupMin.Core" />
      </minifiers>
    </css>
    <js>
      <minifiers>
        <add name="NullJsMinifier" displayName="Null JS Minifier" type="WebMarkupMin.Core.Minifiers.NullJsMinifier, WebMarkupMin.Core" />
        <add name="CrockfordJsMinifier" displayName="Douglas Crockford's JS Minifier" type="WebMarkupMin.Core.Minifiers.CrockfordJsMinifier, WebMarkupMin.Core" />
      </minifiers>
    </js>
    <html whitespaceMinificationMode="Medium" removeHtmlComments="true"
          removeHtmlCommentsFromScriptsAndStyles="true"
          removeCdataSectionsFromScriptsAndStyles="true"
          useShortDoctype="true" useMetaCharsetTag="true"
          emptyTagRenderMode="NoSlash" removeOptionalEndTags="true"
          removeTagsWithoutContent="false" collapseBooleanAttributes="true"
          removeEmptyAttributes="true" attributeQuotesRemovalMode="Html5"
          removeRedundantAttributes="true"
          removeJsTypeAttributes="true" removeCssTypeAttributes="true"
          removeHttpProtocolFromAttributes="false"
          removeHttpsProtocolFromAttributes="false"
          removeJsProtocolFromAttributes="true"
          minifyEmbeddedCssCode="true" minifyInlineCssCode="true"
          minifyEmbeddedJsCode="true" minifyInlineJsCode="true"
          processableScriptTypeList="" minifyKnockoutBindingExpressions="false"
          minifyAngularBindingExpressions="false" customAngularDirectiveList="" />
    <logging>
      <loggers>
        <add name="NullLogger" displayName="Null Logger" type="WebMarkupMin.Core.Loggers.NullLogger, WebMarkupMin.Core" />
        <add name="ThrowExceptionLogger" displayName="Throw exception logger" type="WebMarkupMin.Core.Loggers.ThrowExceptionLogger, WebMarkupMin.Core" />
      </loggers>
    </logging>
  </core>
</webMarkupMin>
```

The html element was added by me manually according to [documentation](http://webmarkupmin.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WebMarkupMin%200.9.2).

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Web application may be in debug mode. In order to switch it to release mode you need to edit the `Web.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    ...
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="false" ... />
        ...
    </system.web>
    ...
</configuration>
```

In addition, you can disable dependence on web application mode. Using the following settings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    ...
    <webMarkupMin xmlns="http://tempuri.org/WebMarkupMin.Configuration.xsd">
        <webExtensions disableMinificationInDebugMode="false"
            disableCompressionInDebugMode="false" />
        ...
    </webMarkupMin>
    ...
</configuration>
```

Comment: Tried this, but am still not getting html minification.

Comment: @brando What version of the WebMarkupMin.Mvc package you are using?

Comment: Hi Andrey, I finally got it working. Works great!  Not sure what I was doing wrong, but whatever it was I fixed it.  Thank you!

Comment: If it doesn't work for someone, try to change maxResponseSize="100000" attribute in webExtensions to some bigger value, e.g. to 1000000, it should fix that issue.

Answer (score 1):

So large library with so difficult usage and configuration... Are you sure need all this for just the HTML minification?

Create a new filter under the Filters subfolder of your project and call it `CompactHtmlFilterAttribute` Use the following code:

```
public class CompactHtmlFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public class WhitespaceFilter : MemoryStream
    {
        private string Source = string.Empty;
        private Stream Filter = null;

        public WhitespaceFilter(HttpResponseBase HttpResponseBase)
        {
            Filter = HttpResponseBase.Filter;
        }

        public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            Source = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer).Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "").Replace("\t", "");
            Filter.Write(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Source), offset, UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(Source));
        }
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        #if DEBUG
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        #else
            try
            {
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Filter = new WhitespaceFilter(filterContext.HttpContext.Response);
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
        #endif
    }
}
```

Pay atention on the `#if DEBUG` dirrective. HTML will be minified only in release configuration, while on debug the original code will be kept for the better readability.

Add this attribute to the controller methods

```
[CompactHtmlFilter]
public ActionResult Index()
{           
    return View();
}
```

and we're done.

Comment: This looks interesting, but I afraid that HTML minification is more complicated and replacing new lines is not allways correct and not enough.  Maybe I try to inject some 3rd party library to write method of your template.

Comment: Absolutely correct :) The most of unnecessary space in HTML come from line feeds and tabs, but there are more points for the further minfication. You can remove comments, if any; you can shorten attributes from type='button' or type="button" to just type=bytton, etc. The beauty of this method is that everything is under your full control.

Comment: @AlexanderDayan : Is there any other option to implement this. Because using this I need to add attribute to all action  method. Is there any way using we can add minification on all pages of site?

Comment: @Ankita You can define the filer scope as global and then apply it to all the actions. See the thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334324/global-action-filter-in-asp-net-mvc for more information.

Comment: @AlexanderDayan : I have written code like this in Global.asax.cs in Application_Start() method to globally work: 
 GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new MinifyHtmlAttribute());
But it gives me an error Filtering is not allowed.

Comment: @AlexanderDayan: This code does not work for me. Moreover, What if I do not want to implement this for debug mode. It should only works on IIS site.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following to enable the webextensions (from the doc):

```
<webMarkupMin xmlns="http://tempuri.org/WebMarkupMin.Configuration.xsd">
  …
  <webExtensions enableMinification="true" disableMinificationInDebugMode="true"
     enableCompression="true" disableCompressionInDebugMode="true"
     maxResponseSize="100000" disableCopyrightHttpHeaders="false" />
  …
</webMarkupMin>
```

Note that it's outside the `<core>` element.

also in your view markup you should have the attribute as:

```
[MinifyHtml]
```

Itshouldn't have the ..Attribute at the end of it.

Comment: in your answer I found maxResponseSize parameter. it looks like that default value is 100000 for maxResponseSize, and in my case minification and compression didn't work. it started working only when I changed maxResponseSize to 1000000.

Thanks!